# How to use metal-cpp with GLFW?

Tags: c++, glfw, metal, metalkit

I'm trying to use the [official metal-cpp headers](https://developer.apple.com/metal/cpp/) to make an entirely C++ metal app using GLFW. I don't want to write any objective-c if possible.

```
#define GLFW_EXPOSE_NATIVE_COCOA
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3native.h>

#include <Metal/Metal.hpp>
#include <MetalKit/MetalKit.hpp>
#include <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.hpp>

int main() {
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow( 1280, 720, "Hello World", nullptr, nullptr);

    auto nswindow = glfwGetCocoaWindow(window);

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        /* Render here */

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know if this is even possible, but my specific hurdle right now is converting the objective-c `NSWindow` returned from `glfwGetCocoaWindow` to an `NS::Window` C++ object.

Comment: GLFW creates an OpenGL for you, it is not designed to work with metal.

Comment: you can't get rid of Objective-C completely. You need a function that gives you the NSWindow* of the underlying GLFWwindow.

Comment: My two cents on the topic: I've tried working with the metal-cpp headers and from my experience I can tell you it's no fun, because it doesn't give you C++-typical abstractions. You are basically still writing Objective-C but with C++ syntax. I found it to be a lot simpler to have a `Renderer` interface, implement a `MetalRenderer` class in Objective-C++ and write all your non-renderering code in normal C++.

Comment: @user7860670 You can use GLFW with any rendering API that your heart desires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get rid of Objective-C(++) completely when using GLFW.

You need a `*.h`/`*.m(m)` combination that adds a Metal Layer to the NSWindow.

```cpp
#ifndef COCOA_BRIDGE
#define COCOA_BRIDGE
#include <metal/metal.hpp>
struct GLFWwindow;

namespace CA {
    class MetalLayer;
}
namespace X {

    void add_layer_to_window(GLFWwindow* window, CA::MetalLayer* layer);
}
#endif
```

```cpp
#import "cocoa_bridge.h"
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#define GLFW_EXPOSE_NATIVE_COCOA
#include <GLFW/glfw3native.h>
#import <QuartzCore/CAMetalLayer.h>
namespace X{

    void add_layer_to_window(GLFWwindow* window, CA::MetalLayer* layer) {
        NSWindow* cocoa_window = glfwGetCocoaWindow(window);
        CAMetalLayer* native_layer = (__bridge CAMetalLayer*)layer;
        [[cocoa_window contentView] setLayer:native_layer];
        [native_layer setMaximumDrawableCount:2];
        [[cocoa_window contentView] setWantsLayer:YES];
        [[cocoa_window contentView] setNeedsLayout:YES];
    }
}
```

```cpp
auto* window = (GLFWwindow*)get_window();
layer = NS::TransferPtr(CA::MetalLayer::layer());
layer->setDevice(device.get());
layer->setFramebufferOnly(true);
layer->setPixelFormat(MTL::PixelFormat::PixelFormatBGRA8Unorm_sRGB);
add_layer_to_window(window, layer.get());
```

the whole rendering happens then via the layer.